# How to check if a file exists in a folder starting with a substring and ending with a substring in Python

Tags: python, string, while-loop, python-os

I wanna wait for a file to donwload, and I want to check on a folder while the file not exists I'll put a time untill the file finish the download. The problem is I wanna check if the file exists starting with a substring variable called 'final_name' and ends with '.csv'. Could someone help me?

```
    final_name = name.replace(" ", "").replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('-', '')\
        .replace('/', '').replace(r"'", '')

    print(final_name)

    time.sleep(5)

    while not os.path.exists(final_name):
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: `Could someone help me?` - Which part do you need help with?

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), [https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to check if the file exists. It lists all files in a directory and loops over them and checks if a file starts and ends with the specified strings.

Code:

```
import os

def path_exists(directory, start, end):
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith(start) and file.endswith(end):
            return True
    return False

# "./" is the current directory.
print(path_exists("./", final_name, ".csv"))
```

Comment: But this function will wait until the file has been created?

Comment: @JhonattaSilva you can use this function instead of `os.path.exists()` in your example, then it will wait until the file is created.